# ¿Como es la sentencia SQL adecuada para insertar una imagen en una base de datos MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando introducir una serie de imágenes a una BD en MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE DATOS_USUARIO (

CODIGO_USUARIO INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
NOMBRE VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
FOTO LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(CODIGO_USUARIO)
);

INSERT INTO DATOS_USUARIO (NOMBRE,FOTO) VALUES ('Nombre 1','/home/mangel/Documentos/ImagenesLucha/Imagen.jpg');
```

Solo quiero saber si esa es la manera correcta de insertar una imagen en una BD de MySQL tomando en cuenta que para las imágenes estoy utilizando un dato de tipo LONGBLOB.
Cabe mencionar y como muchos sabrán:
/home/mangel/Documentos/ImagenesLucha/Imagen.jpg es la ruta dónde tengo almacenadas las imágenes en mi PC y que posteriormente insertaré en la BD.

Comment: ¿Cuando dices "insertar una imagen" te refieres a literalmente guardar el archivo de la imagen en la DB o a la ruta de la misma?, si es lo primero no te lo recomiendo, es mejor opción guardar la imagen en el servidor y en la DB solo guardar la ubicación para que se cargue con algún front-end.

Comment: Si me comentaron que guardar imágenes en una DB no es muy beneficioso, solo para aclarar, ¿Como se guardaría la ruta de la imagen en un servidor, por ejemplo si mi servidor fuera mi propia PC, entonces solo tendría que insertar la ruta de cada una de las imágenes en la DB y entonces que tendría que insertar la ruta en dónde tenga almacenadas las imágenes en mi PC?

Answer (score 0):

Para cargar una imagen en MySQL debes usar php u otro lenguaje del lado del servidor con ese comando lo único que cargaras es el texto encerrado entre comillas

> VALUES ('Nombre 1','/home/mangel/Documentos/ImagenesLucha/Imagen.jpg');

Una imagen es un archivo codificado en un patrón especifico según su formato si abres una imagen con un editor Hexadecimal podrás ver el contenido de la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno todo ese contenido deberías digitarlo entre las comillas para replicar la imagen, desconozco, pero dudo que haya un método en MySQL para cargar las imágenes de manera directa, que alguien me corrija. de todos modos y como te comento hay muchos tutoriales para cargar imágenes en MySQL te dejo aquí el link de uno: [Cargar imágenes a MySQL usando PHP](https://www.baulphp.com/cargar-y-almacenar-imagen-en-mysql-php/)

saludos.